# Notepad++'s incorrect function list functionality

Tags: c, regex, notepad++

Notepad++ has a built-in functionality called function list, which displays function names that are present in the current file. Unfortunately Notepad++ doesn't detect C functions that have a function pointer in the definition:

```
//not detected
void A( void( *call )( void )  )
{

}

//ok
void B( void  )
{

}
```

Notepad stores these rules in the file *functionList.xml*, and it has a rule for C functions:

```
    <parser id="c_function" displayName="C source" commentExpr="((/\*.*?\*)/|(//.*?$))">
        <function
            mainExpr="^[\t ]*((static|const|virtual)[\s]+)?[\w:]+([\s]+[\w]+)?([\s]+|\*[\s]+|[\s]+\*|[\s]+\*[\s]+)([\w_]+[\s]*::)?(?!(if|while|for))[\w_]+[\s]*\([^\)\(]*\)([\s]*const[\s]*)?[\n\s]*\{"
            displayMode="$functionName">
            <functionName>
                <nameExpr expr="(?!(if|while|for))[\w_~]+[\s]*\("/>
                <nameExpr expr="(?!(if|while|for))[\w_~]+"/>
            </functionName>
        </function>
    </parser>
```

As you can see the regex `mainExpr` is rather long and my understanding of regex is not sufficient to also include function pointers in the rule.

C Function pointers can be rather complex, for example:

```
void ( *C( int a, void(*f)( int ) ) ) ( int )
{
    ( void )a;
    ( void )f;

    void(*b)( int ) = NULL;

    return b;
}
```

I'm looking for solutions to modify the regex rule so it will detect the example function A ( and if possible also C. )

Comment: Try adding `|^void\s+\w*\(.*?\)[\n\s]*\{` at the end of the `mainExpr`.

Comment: Where is this "function list" in the menus?

Comment: @ooga View->Function List

Comment: @this I use this editor, but clicking that menu item (when a C file is loaded) just shows an empty side panel.

Comment: ... which is because I don't tell the editor it's a C file, as I hate all that garish highlited syntax.

Answer (score 1):

In order to match those C functions you can try using the following regex:

```
^[\t ]*((static|const|virtual)[\s]+)?[\w:]+([\s]+[\w]+)?([\s]+|\*[\s]+|[\s]+\*|[\s]+\*[\s]+)([\w_]+[\s]*::)?(?!(if|while|for))([\w_]*[\s]*)\([^()]*(\([^()]*(\([^()]*\)[^()]*)*\))*[^()]*\)(\s*\([^()]*(\([^()]*(\([^()]*\)[^()]*)*\))*[^()]*\))*([\s]*const[\s]*)?[\n\s]*\{
```

The problem is we cannot be too sure if the regex in the Notepad++ function list supports recursion. If it does support recursion, the regex would be safer:

```
^[\t ]*((static|const|virtual)[\s]+)?[\w:]+([\s]+[\w]+)?([\s]+|\*[\s]+|[\s]+\*|[\s]+\*[\s]+)([\w_]+[\s]*::)?(?!(if|while|for))([\w_]*[\s]*)(\s*\((?>[^()]|(?8))*\))*(\s*\((?>[^()]|(?9))*\))*([\s]*const[\s]*)?[\n\s]*\{
```

Comment: That only detects function starting with void.

Comment: @stribizhev My examples start with void, but not all C function do. It should match valid C syntax functions with function pointers. Can't we replace ^\s*void with something else?

Comment: Unfortunately, that breaks it completely.

Comment: I have updated the answer, but I doubt there is a 100% safe and correct regex for this.

Comment: It works now, but it also gives some false positives. :-/ Thank for your effort though.